# Read a Excel stream async

Tags: c#, excel, async-await, .net-core, csvhelper

I have a web api developed in net core that reads some large files from a stream. These files have been *csv* so far and I've been using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a very performant and complete library that I highly recommend) to achieve this.

The thing is that I need to support *xlsx* files now and I want to do it in the same way as I've been working with the *csv*, asynchronously.

The code I have is this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    using (var csvParser = new CsvParser(reader))
    {
        IList<string> row = await csvParser.ReadAsync();

        // continue reading and working with the file

    }
}
```

I have found [NPOI](https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI) and [EPPlus.Core](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core) but I didn't see any way to work with the stream asynchronously. As far as I get it, with these libraries you need to have all the stream in memory before starting to work with it. Do you guys know any library compatible with net core that allows you to work asynchronously in order to avoid loading the whole file into memory?

Comment: I've used [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) successfully. See if this helps.

Comment: Maybe with pkg DocumentFormat.OpenXml.  And some magic after SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, bool)